# freeze layers while passing a part of features

Tags: keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to design a network using keras like this pic. And there is a problem I need some help. F* is a feature tensor like a sentence or a picture, the shared layers is a block comprise several layers. F* will merge together after passing the shared layer. Then merged feature will pass an output layer. The structure is described below.

**The problem is I want to train this network only use F1. Namely, when F2 pass the shared layers, shared layers are frozen.**

I would very appreciate if you could answer me with pseudocode.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.ipynb. It is from Chollet's book, which I recommend. This chapter describes merging models and earlier chapters describe freezing layers. I haven't done both simultaneously, so I don't have any working code.

Comment: @fromkerasimportmichael thank you I've found another way to solve this problem